# how to update multiple columns of pandas dataframe inplace and in single instance

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

consider below `pandas` DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,15).reshape(-1,3), columns = list('abc'))
```

i want to update values of all the three columns as ratios in place (ie columns values divided by sum of all three columns, axis = 1) in a single instance.

something like:

```
df = df.loc[:,['a','b','c']] / df.loc[:,['a','b','c']].sum(axis = 1)
```

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.div](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) method:

```
df.div(df.sum())

#          a           b           c
#0  0.071429    0.368421    0.173913
#1  0.214286    0.210526    0.391304
#2  0.214286    0.052632    0.043478
#3  0.285714    0.105263    0.130435
#4  0.214286    0.263158    0.260870
```

---

To divide by rows, specify axis accordingly:

```
df1 = df.div(df.sum(axis = 1), axis = 0)
```

Here is a test that the result data frame has rowsum of one.

```
df1.sum(axis = 1)

#0    1.0
#1    1.0
#2    1.0
#3    1.0
#4    1.0
#dtype: float64
```

Comment: i cannot do this with axis set to 1 (horizontal). Although this works if the axis is set to 0 (vertical). In which case I have to transpose the df. something like: df.T.div(df.T.sum()).T

Comment: Check the update, you need to specify axis accordingly in the two functions.